# Подсчитывание количества переменных введёных пользователем

Tags: c#, ооп

Как создать то или иное количество переменных в зависимости от введёных цифр, например 7,6,12,4.

Comment: В этом случае данные стоит хранить, например, в массиве

Comment: @regent,Хорошо, но что нужно чтобы программа распознала например 3 и 1243?

Comment: что значит `распознала`?

Comment: Ну допустим ввожу  я цифры 1 14 163 2467 через пробел и как распознать и записать в массив эти цифры?

Comment: Считать как строку, разделить строку по пробелу на несколько строк с числами, каждую из строк-чисел спарсить в число, результат записать в массив.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` чтобы считать строку. `String.Split()` чтобы разделить. `int.Parse()` чтобы парсить.

Comment: @tym32167, это то что мне нужно, можете оформить как ответ я его засчитаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо считать строку, разделить строку по пробелу на несколько строк с числами, каждую из строк-чисел спарсить в число, результат записать в массив.

[Console.ReadLine()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.7.2) чтобы считать строку. [String.Split()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) чтобы разделить. [int.Parse()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) чтобы парсить.